# C# TLSharp получить сообщение (TLMessage) из канала

Tags: c#, telegram, tlsharp

С помощью TLSharp получаю список сообщений с канала, мне нужно взять последнее опубликованное сообщение и получить информацию о нем, а именно:

текст сообщения, тип вложений (фото\видео\аудио и т.д.), количество вложений.

Использую следующий код:

**Получаю канал**:

```
public async Task<TLChannel> GetChannel(string username)
    {
        if (!_authorized)
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Not authorized");
        TLRequestResolveUsername requestResolveUsername = new TLRequestResolveUsername()
        {
            Username = username
        };

        TLResolvedPeer peer = await _client.SendRequestAsync<TLResolvedPeer>(requestResolveUsername);

        TLChannel channel = (TLChannel)peer.Chats.First();
        return channel;
    }
```

**Получаю последнее сообщение в канале:**

```
 public async Task<TLMessage> GetLastMessage(TLChannel channelFrom)
    {
        TLChannelMessages resp = (TLChannelMessages)await _client.GetHistoryAsync(new TLInputPeerChannel()
        {
            ChannelId = channelFrom.Id,
            AccessHash = channelFrom.AccessHash ?? 0,
        }, limit: 1000);

        TLMessage lastMessage = (TLMessage)resp.Messages?.Where(x => x is TLMessage).First();
        return lastMessage;
    }
```

В результате выходит переменная TLMessage.

С помощью **lastMessage.Message** получаю текст сообщения, **lastMessage.Id** = ID сообщения.

Как можно узнать есть ли с сообщением прикрепленные файлы (фото\видео и т.д.) и их количество?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я к сожалению не знаю, как это работает, но погуглил, покопался в гитхабе, и думаю, что вот так можно определить конкретный тип `TLMessage.Media`.

```cs
TLMessage message = await GetLastMessage(channel);

switch (message.Media)
{
    case TLMessageMediaContact contact:
        // это контакт
        break;
    case TLMessageMediaDocument document:
        // это документ
        break;
    case TLMessageMediaGame game:
        // это игра
        break;
    case TLMessageMediaGeo geo:
        // это геолокация
        break;
    case TLMessageMediaInvoice invoice:
        // это деньги
        break;
    case TLMessageMediaPhoto photo:
        // это картинки
        break;
    case TLMessageMediaVenue venue:
        // это место проведения мероприятия
        break;
    case TLMessageMediaWebPage webPage:
        // это веб-страница
        break;
    case TLMessageMediaUnsupported unsupported:
        // TLSharp не понял, что это такое
        break;
    case TLMessageMediaEmpty empty:
        // пусто
        break;
    case default:
        // null или тип, который не перечислен выше
        break;
}
```

После определения типа можно обращаться к конкретному объекту, например `photo.Photo`. Вам необязательно всё перечисленное обрабатывать, вы можете выкинуть лишнее из кода, и оставить только типы, которые хотите поддерживать. Если выкинуть ветку, то будет срабатывать `case default` для тех веток, которых нет.

Там еще есть `message.Entities`, которые тоже могут содержать что-то полезное. Поддержки фотоальбома в одном сообщении я что-то не нашел. В любом случае `TLSharp` поддерживет возможность реализации остуствующих в самом фреймворке методов на основе родной телеграмовской API.

*Кстати, сам `TLSharp` очень сложно написан, куча пустых абстракций, используемых как интерфейсы, автор явно не особо заморачивался с дизайном этого всего, а просто писал код под какую-то свою задачу, а потом выложил, что получилось. Везде эти повторяющиеся префиксы, у автора явно проблемы с ООП и правилами именования классов. В общем, я сломал себе глаза в [гитхабе](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp), и не знаю, как вам еще помочь.*

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, буду пробовать разбираться дальше